# Feasible to use an exercise step with risers as a bench?

Tags: exercise-equipment

I want to stepping and benching to my exercise routine. Instead of two pieces of equipment, is it feasible to also use a step with risers as a bench?

I know I could use a bench as a stepper, but as best I can tell, there's just one flat height for a bench and therefore one height for a stepper.

My preference is an adjustable step that can be used as a bench.

But is that feasible (safety, comfort, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would caution against using a stepper as a bench press bench.

Part of the reason why benches are so high, is because if you fail a rep, there needs to be some height to it so you can load the weight off to one of the sides, and escape the bar.

Also, a stepper is a hard plastic surface. With the way we place our scapulae on the bench for the press, some padding is needed.

So as for your question, both for safety and comfort, I strongly advise against using a stepper as bench press support.